# How to do Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic for GEV distribution in R?

Tags: r, distribution, data-fitting, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am now using the `extremes` package to fit a generalized extreme value (GEV) distribution, and I want to use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to estimate the goodness of fit, but get the following error:

```
library(extRemes)
library(eva)
data("PORTw", package = "extRemes")
fit1 <- fevd(TMX1, PORTw, units = "deg C")
ks.test(PORTw$TMX1,"pgev",fit1$results$par[[1]],fit1$results$par[[2]],shape=fit1$results$par[[3]])

`Warning message:
In ks.test(PORTw$TMX1, "pgev", fit1$results$par[[1]], fit1$results$par[[2]],  :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test`
```

So, my question is, how to perform a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for the GEV fit with ties? Or, is there any other goodness of fit test for fitting a distribution available in R? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You "wonder how to do this `this == _what_?` in R". You cannot possibly be asking how to do a KS test in R, right? At least not without doing your own search, right?

Comment: Sorry for the vague question and I have edited it with more information.

Comment: That was only a warning. You should have seen at the console (but failed to copy the output) results from a KS-test. Again ... can you explain in a complete natural language manner what the statistical question really is? Or why you think the output is incorrect? Perhaps you need to read some statistical theory that will explain why ties are not expected with a KS test? Or post on CrossValidated.com with a question about the underlying theory and what degree of worry to apply to this event?

Comment: You might want to actually _look_ at your data: `table(PORTw$TMX1)`

Comment: Thanks. I do not notice that this is only a warning and I can see the results. The question is, is there any statistical difference between `fit1 ` and a theoretical GEV distribution? The aim is to evaluate the goodness of fit for the `fit1`model.

Comment: If reading the Details section of the help for `?ks.test` and `?fevd` (which apparently you did not already do) is not enough then you should send your "methods/theory question" over to CrossValidated.com where such matters are on-topic. I don't think this is on-topic for SO. My close vote is actually a "migrate vote".

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have read the details for `fevd`, but it only provides some qualitative plotting methods for evaluating the goodness of fit. I want to use the K-S test to give me a quantitative result (I have seen such method on published papers). Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is quite a bit of misapplied statistical testing in the "published literature" of various fields. The literature may only be giving a guide to what can be slipped past statistically ignorant reviewers in say the medical or business domains. You would be well advised to get advice from a real statistician who has experience in extreme value theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the "EnvStats" package.
You will have more versatility for goodness of fit test:

```
library(EnvStats)
# For a data set called X
X <- rgevd(500)
# Generalized Extreme Value (EnvStats)
egevd(X, method = "mle")# Maximum likelihood
# Goodness of fit test
gofTest(X, distribution = "gev",test = "ks")#Kolmogorov-Smirnov
gofTest(X, distribution = "gev",test = "chisq")#Chi-Squared
```

Comment: So how about Generalized Pareto distribution? I can't assign the distribution="gp" in this"gofTest" function (seems not supporting it). If you could give a hint please.